# If I import bookmarks from Firefox and Chrome, from Windows to Ubuntu, will browser viruses be transferred also?

Tags: malware

My Windows browsers have a "Hello User" virus. I'm afraid to import bookmarks to Chromium and Firefox in Ubuntu. Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Importing your bookmarks will have no adverse affect on your Ubuntu browsers. They're not what contains the malicious code that's affecting your Windows system (the code is embedded in the Windows registry).